# Array Checking Out of Bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

**I'm making a Bejewelled Style game.** 
I have used a 8x8 2D array to store Coordinates(X/Y axis) for each "Gem". I am trying to Detect and remove Three gems in a row using another Horizontally and Vertical 2D arrays filled with 0 and adding 1 every time an adjacent gem is detected:

eg. C F F E E E A D would be  0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0

However I am getting some "out of bounds" results where each horizontal/vertical check goes outside that row or column. 
**How would I implement some boundaries for my check?**

```
    void CheckGemLine(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
    int HorizontalBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
    int VerticalBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];

    for( int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS ; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            HorizontalBoard[row][column] = 0;
            VerticalBoard[row][column] = 0;

            if (board[row][column] == board[row][column + 1] || board[row][column] == board[row][column - 1] )
            {
                HorizontalBoard[row][column]++;
                if (board[row][column] == board[row][column + 1] && board[row][column] == board[row][column - 1])
                {
                    HorizontalBoard[row][column]++;
                }
            }
            printf("%d ",HorizontalBoard[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS ; i++) //Loop for replacing Gems with 'X'
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            if(HorizontalBoard[i][j] == 2)
            {
                board[i][j] = 'X';
                board[i][j+1]= 'X';
                board[i][j-1]= 'X';
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going out of bounds because if you were to check the left column and right column, if you are at the first column, checking the left column goes out of bounds... and if you are at the last column, checking the right column also goes out of bounds.  As such, make sure in your first set of `for` loops you check to see if `column - 1 > 0` and `column + 1 < MAX_COLUMNS`.  Similarly, for the other `for` loop, do what al-acme has suggested in his/her answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place these lines under condition:

```
board[i][j+1]= 'X';
board[i][j-1]= 'X';
```

Like this:

```
board[i][j] = 'X';
if(j+1 < MAX_COLUMNS)
    board[i][j+1]= 'X';
if(j-1 >= 0)
    board[i][j-1]= 'X';
```

The same should be in other places where you are doing `column + 1` or `column - 1`. This is what your Array `board` would look like:

```
assuming j ---goes this way--> 
00    01    02    03    04    05    
10    11    12    13    14    15    
20    21    22    23    24    25    
30    31    32    33    34    35    
40    41    42    43    44    45    
50    51    52    53    54    55
```

So see what `j-1` does when `i` and `j` both are `0` - it makes you access `board[0][0-1]` = `board[0][-1]` --> which does not exists in your array. Now imagine when `i` and `j` both are `MAX_COLUMNS-1` or `MAX_ROWS-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you want to use a variable as the index of the array you should have a check.

```
if (board[row][column] == board[row][column + 1] || board[row][column] == board[row][column - 1] )
```

should be like this:

```
if ((column + 1 < MAX_COLUMNS && board[row][column] == board[row][column + 1]) || ( column - 1 >= 0)  && board[row][column] == board[row][column - 1]) )
```

And you have the same problem in the following code like @al-Acme mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A classical approach to avoid the boundary check is to enlarge the matrix in each direction with a *empty case*.

In your case you can just iterate from 1 to `Column - 1` when checking horizontally, and similarly for vertical case:

```
void CheckGemLine(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
    // Horizontal check

    // ={} to initialize array with value 0
    int HorizontalBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS] = {}; 

    for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS ; row++) {
        for(int column = 1; column < MAX_COLUMNS - 1; column++) {
            if (board[row][column] == board[row][column - 1]) {
                HorizontalBoard[row][column]++;
            }
            if (board[row][column] == board[row][column + 1]) {
                HorizontalBoard[row][column]++;
            }
        }
    }
    // Vertical check now
    int VerticalBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS] = {};

    for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS - 1 ; row++) {
        for(int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++) {
            if (board[row][column] == board[row + 1][column]) {
                VerticalBoard[row][column]++;
                VerticalBoard[row + 1][column]++;
            }
        }
    }
    // Replace with 'X' now
    // By construction of HorizontalBoard&VerticalBoard,
    // there is no out of bound accesses.
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNS; j++) {
        {
            if (HorizontalBoard[i][j] == 2)
            {
                // HorizontalBoard[i][0] cannot be 2
                // HorizontalBoard[i][MAX_COLUMNS - 1] cannot be 2
                board[i][j-1]= 'X';
                board[i][j] = 'X';
                board[i][j+1]= 'X';
            }
            if (VerticalBoard[i][j] == 2)
            {
                // HorizontalBoard[0][j] cannot be 2
                // HorizontalBoard[MAX_ROWS - 1][j] cannot be 2
                board[i - 1][j]= 'X';
                board[i][j] = 'X';
                board[i + 1][j]= 'X';
            }
        }
    }
}
```